# Matlab mex wrappers within opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex

I am trying to use Matlab mex wrappers provided by the OpenCV contrib repository https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/matlab.
During the OpenCV installation everything goes fine and cmake can find Matlab installation. My OS is ubuntu 16.04 64 bit and I am using Matlab R2015b.

After successful installation, in order to solve conflicts due to internal dynamic libraries, I have put libstdc++ or libgcc_s in the LD_PRELOAD variable before launching matlab. Moreover, based on opencv documentation (opencv_contrib/modules/matlab/) I have added the binding to the matlab path using "addpath('/path/to/opencv/matlab/');"

after running the following code (provided in the opencv documentation):

```
% load an image (Matlab)
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
% compute the DFT (OpenCV)
If = cv.dft(I, cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
```

My code works fine, but whenever I use

```
I=imread('cameraman.tif');
cv.imshow('test',I)
```

or

```
cv.imread('cameraman.tif');
```

(or I think all modules provided in the opencv highgui module), I face with the following error in matlab:

Invalid MEX-file '/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/matlab/+cv/imread.mexa64': /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1:
undefined symbol: _ZN11xercesc_3_111InputSource11setEncodingEPKt

I searched a lot to solve the problem, but I couldn't achieve any success. I also tried to build opencv with the flag -D WITH_GDAL=OFF during the opencv cmake installation, but not only it solves the problem, but also makes matlab crash after calling the above-mentioned codes.

Comment: P.S. I am using OpenCV 3.1.0

Comment: have you tried cv.imread on a different file format?

Comment: yes I have used it also for 'lena.jpg' but I receive the same error.